# Is there a Pythonic way to delete common indexes in multiple lists?

Tags: python, list

Say I want to delete index `i` from `alist` and `blist`. Is there a clean, Pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: `alist.pop(i)` `blist.pop(i)` or `del alist[i]` `del blist[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight-forward way is usually the most Pythonic:

```
for seq in (alist, blist):
    del seq[i]
```

That said, if you find the need to do this more than once, it is usually more efficient to build new lists than to do multiple deletions from the same list:

```
# Slow O(n) operations where i > j > k
del seq[i]
del seq[j]
del seq[k]

# Better (one pass)
targets = {i, j, k}
seq[:] = [x for i, x in seq if i not in targets]
```

Comment: Has a side effect of leaving the `seq` variable behind.